# Understanding Closure Compiler warnings

Tags: javascript, android, google-closure-compiler, duktape

I am in the process of using Google's closure compiler to optimize+ obfuscate code which I run in an Android app via Duktape.  I have successfully dealt with the majority of the warning messages that Closure throws back at me.  However, there are a few which leave me stumped.  What I should do in order to deal with them?

```
var Uny = 
  {"version":1, "d":new Date(), "uOff":new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*60}
```

`accessing name Date in externs has no effect. Perhaps you forgot to add a var keyword?`

This is an object I declare in the `externs.js` file I provide to Closure CLI.

```
function moreSlotsToCome(slots,ndx)
{
 var i,range;
 for(i= ndx + 1;i < slots.length;i++)
 {
  range = makeRange(slots[i]);
  if (range[0] == range[1]) break;
  return 1;
 } 
 return 0;
}
```

which throws up `WARNING - unreachable code` with the `^^^` error indicator pointing to `i++` in the for loop above.

```
  var obj = JSON.parse(iBridge.rule()),
  keys = Object.keys(obj);

WARNING - actual parameter 1 of Object.keys does not match formal parameter
found   : *
required: Object
```

with the `^^^` indicator pointing to the `obj` in `Object.keys(obj)`.  I realize that `JSON.parse()` here could return `null` so I tried to put in an explicit test for `null` but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WARNING - accessing name Date in externs has no effect. Perhaps you forgot to add a var keyword?

Externs should only be type declarations. In general, they should not contain executable code (the right-hand side of an expression). Write your extern like:

```
/** @const */
var Uny = {};
/** @type {number} */ Uny.version;
/** @type {!Date} */ Uny.d;
/** @type {number} */ Uny.uOff;
```

> WARNING - unreachable code

Your loop body will only ever execute once. You have an unconditional exit `return 1` so the compiler is correct, `i++` will never execute. This probably shouldn't be a loop.

> WARNING - actual parameter 1 of Object.keys does not match formal parameter

In addition to `null`, `JSON.parse` can also return primitives such as `boolean`, `number`, and `string`. These aren't objects and don't have keys. They are frequently promoted to an object through the concept of auto-boxing.

If you can **guaranteee** that the return value is an Object, you can type cast it.

```
var obj = /** @type {Object} */ (JSON.parse(iBridge.rule()))
```

The extra parenthesis are required.

Comment: Thanks - I had tried typecasting but I was missing the parentheses.  Actually in the end I ended up using the excellent [JavascriptObfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator) since the output from Closure was not really obscure - fair enough, it never claims to be an obfuscator. The bloated code size from the obfuscator does not appear to have an impact on my app.  However, I have discovered the benefits of using Closure as a means of checking JS code - as you found I did have an error up there which resulted in unreachable code.  Thank you Google!